# Google DataFlow sample TrafficStreamingMaxLaneFlow excution

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have succeeded to run the WordCount sample but failed  to run TrafficStreamingMaxLaneFlow  sample what arguments exactly I should use?.
My command line: 
`mvn exec:java -pl examples -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.TrafficStreamingMaxLaneFlow -Dexec.args="--project=sturdy-analyzer-658 --inputTopic=xxxInputTopic --dataset=xxxDataset --table=MIS --runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner"`

The result:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) on project google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Failed to construct instance from factory method com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner#fromOptions: Missing required value: at least one of tempLocation or stagingLocation must be set. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Avi, add a stagingLocation arg to your invocation, along these lines:

```
--stagingLocation=gs://your-bucket/staging
```

Make sure this is a bucket in your project that you have write access to.